# Where can I find Copper Ore?

Tags: portal-knights

To make a door, I need 2 Copper Bars, and to make them, I need Copper Ores.

[image: Copper Ore]

How can I find some Copper Ores?  I had some in my inventory so I don't think that it is a quest reward etc. but I think that it is a drop from monsters or a spawn underground as an ore. Does it drop from monsters or does it spawn underground, or does it come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more monster hunting, I found out that they drop from "Bomb Gazer"s.

[image: Bomb Gazer]

After some mining, I also found that they are also available as ores, doesn't even have to be underground!

[image: Copper Ore]